# Cannot get the input values inside the User Control Button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, user-controls

When i click into the Button which is placed inside a usercontrol, i dont get the values that are inputted into the textbox on the button click event. please suggest any alternate.

my UserControl Markup:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SearchPopup.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="trg.dgs.sites.web.ui.ui.charternew.usercontrol.SearchPopup" %>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //    function searchPopuptester() {

    //        debugger;

    //        var address = document.getElementById('<%= txtAddress.ClientID  %>').value;
    //        //alert(address);
    //        var zip = document.getElementById('<%= txtZip.ClientID %>').value;
    //        // alert(zip);
    //        var aptnum = document.getElementById('<%= txtSuite.ClientID %>').value;
    //        alert(aptnum);

    //        debugger;
    //        $.ajax({
    //            type: "GET",
    //            url: "ui/charternew/usercontrol/SearchPopup.ascx/SearchAddress",
    //            data: [{ address: address, suite: aptnum, zip: zip}],
    //            datatype: "json",
    //            success: function (data) {
    //                window.location = data.d;
    //            },
    //            failure: function () {
    //                alert("Sorry,there is a error!");
    //            }
    //        });
    //    }


</script>
<div class="form_wrapper">
    <div class="formarea">
        <div class="form_heading">
            <h4>
                Check Service Availability</h4>
            <p>
                TO FIND THE BEST DEALS IN YOUR AREA</p>
        </div>
        dddddddddddd
        <p>
            <img src="ui/charternew/images/lock_icon.png" alt="Lock Icon" class="lock_icon" />Your
            Information is Private and Secure</p>
        <div class="feild_set">
            <div class="feild_bar">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" MaxLength="30" CssClass="feild1" />
            </div>
            <div class="feild_bar">
                <div class="apt_feild">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSuite" runat="server" MaxLength="25" CssClass="feild2" />
                </div>
                <div class="zipcode_feild">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" MaxLength="5" CssClass="feild2" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="feild_bar">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Ismoving" CssClass="tflables" TextAlign="right" runat="server"
                    Checked="false" />
                <label>
                    Moving?</label>
                <label id="lblMoveDate" style="display: none;">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtmovedate" runat="server" CssClass="txtfield" MaxLength="50" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click">Find My BEST Deals</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <!-- End Form -->
    </div>
</div>
```

My UserControl Code:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


string add = txtAddress.Text;            }
```

Comment: where is button control on page or on usercontrol

Comment: What does javascript:search(); return false; do in your code?

Comment: @Alborz Please ignore javascript:search(); return false; . this function is commented

Comment: @geek the button control is in the usercontrol.

Comment: please paste complete markup

Comment: its not actually giving any error. the problem is, i dont get the value of the input text. i get it null on submit click while debuging.